# Memory crash while computing data augmentation with python for deep learning

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management, out-of-memory, ram

I am working on classifying different kinds of signals with deep learning. The dataset I have is kinda small and obtaining more data(signals) is a bit expensive. The idea is to do data augmentation and I am using the code below to do so. However, apparently, 12GB of RAM isn't enough to do so (with an input (initial dataset size)  of 1200) and the machine crashes eventually.

Is there any idea/suggestion on how I can improve this code in a more memory-friendly way?

```
def sliding_window(data, labels, window_sz, n_hop, n_start=0, show_status=False):
    """    
    input: (array) data : matrix to be processed    
           (int)   window_sz : nb of samples to be used in the window    
           (int)   n_hop : size of jump between windows    
    output:(array) new_data : output matrix of size (None, window_sz, feature_dim)    
    """    
    flag = 0    
    for sample in range(data.shape[0]):    
        tmp = np.array(
            [data[sample, i:i + window_sz, :] for i in np.arange(n_start, data.shape[1] - window_sz + n_hop, n_hop)])
        tmp_lab = np.array([labels[sample] for i in np.arange(n_start, data.shape[1] - window_sz + n_hop, n_hop)])
        if sample % 100 == 0 and show_status == True:
            print("Sample " + str(sample) + "processed!\n")
        if flag == 0:
            new_data = tmp
            new_lab = tmp_lab
            flag = 1
        else:
            new_data = np.concatenate((new_data, tmp))
            new_lab = np.concatenate((new_lab, tmp_lab))
    return new_data, new_lab
```

and this is how I'm using it

```
x_augmented, y_augmented = sliding_window(data = X_train[:,:,:],
                                                 labels = y_train[:],
                                                 window_sz = 4 * fs,
                                                 n_hop = fs // 10,
                                                 n_start = fs * 1)
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: why is your code double/triple spaced?

Comment: sorry about that, i removed the extra spaces